# DISNAKE | Как сделать задержку в командах?

Tags: python, discord

Речь идёт не о `time.sleep()`. Допустим есть команда "ban", как сделать задержку так, чтобы её можно было использовать допустим раз в 30секунд?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте `@commands.cooldown`. Предположим Вам нужно сделать команду которую можно будет использовать раз в `30` секунд `1` раз:

```
@commands.cooldown(1, 30, commands.BucketType.user)
```

> `1` — кол-во использований команды для установленного промежутка времени.

> `30` — время спустя которое команда будет доступна (в секундах).

> `commands.BucketType.user` — cooldown для конкретного пользователя

Для установки cooldown'а для всего сервера, используйте `BucketType.guild`.

Comment: ***Если я Вам помог, отметьте этот ответ галочкой и полезным.***